# Separar lista de nomes de acordo com notas com regex

Tags: python, regex

Como resolver isso com regex?

> O arquivo `assets/grades.txt` contém uma lista de pessoas - uma por linha - contendo suas notas. Crie uma regex para gerar uma lista dos alunos que receberam nota B.

Arquivo `assets/grades.txt`:

```
Ronald Mayr: A
Bell Kassulke: B
Jacqueline Rupp: A 
Alexander Zeller: C
Valentina Denk: C 
Simon Loidl: B 
Elias Jovanovic: B 
Stefanie Weninger: A 
Fabian Peer: C 
Hakim Botros: B
Emilie Lorentsen: B
Herman Karlsen: C
Nathalie Delacruz: C
Casey Hartman: C
Lily Walker : A
Gerard Wang: C
Tony Mcdowell: C
Jake Wood: B
Fatemeh Akhtar: B
Kim Weston: B
Nicholas Beatty: A
Kirsten Williams: C
Vaishali Surana: C
Coby Mccormack: C
Yasmin Dar: B
Romy Donnelly: A
Viswamitra Upandhye: B
Kendrick Hilpert: A
Killian Kaufman: B
Elwood Page: B
Mukti Patel: A
Emily Lesch: C
Elodie Booker: B
Jedd Kim: A
Annabel Davies: A
Adnan Chen: B
Jonathan Berg: C
Hank Spinka: B
Agnes Schneider: C
Kimberly Green: A
Lola-Rose Coates: C
Rose Christiansen: C
Shirley Hintz: C
Hannah Bayer: B
```

Minha tentativa:

```
import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()
        #print(grades)
 
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    B_entities = re.finditer("(?P<name>[\w ]*):\s(?P<grade>B$)", grades)
    counter = 0
    for item in B_entities:
        print(item.groupdict(['name']))
        counter += 1
    print(counter)
 
    return B_entities
 
grades()
```

Comment: Opa, essa comunidade é em português. Recomendo editar a pergunta traduzida e incluindo o exemplo de código que você tentou, já que ele também faz parte da pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa ler todo o conteúdo do arquivo de uma vez para depois iterar por ele com `finditer`. Se cada aluno está em uma linha, você pode ler uma linha por vez (para arquivos pequenos talvez não faça diferença, mas para arquivos maiores fará, pois `read()` carrega todo o conteúdo do arquivo para a memória).

Para ler linha a linha, basta iterar pelo arquivo com um `for`:

```
import re

r = re.compile('^([^:]+): B')
alunosComNotaB = []
with open('grades.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        match = r.match(linha)
        if match:
            alunosComNotaB.append(match.group(1))

print(alunosComNotaB)
```

Na regex eu uso o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` (que indica o início da linha) e em seguida uso `[^:]+` (um ou mais caracteres [que não sejam](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `:`, assim eu garanto que vou pegar tudo até os dois pontos - estou assumindo que o nome não tem `:`). E tudo isso está entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim eu consigo pegar essa informação depois, com o [método `group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group).

Depois eu vejo se a nota é "B" (e aqui eu assumo que depois dos `:` sempre tem um espaço e depois a nota). Eu coloquei a nota B diretamente, pois se a nota for diferente, a regex não encontrará nenhum *match* e não entrará no `if`. Mas eu também poderia ter feito de maneira mais genérica para pegar a nota:

```
# assumindo que a nota pode ser de "A" a "F"
r = re.compile(r'^([^:]+):\s*([A-F])')
alunosComNotaB = []
with open('grades.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        match = r.match(linha)
        if match and match.group(2) == 'B':
            alunosComNotaB.append(match.group(1))
```

Usei `\s*` (zero ou mais espaços), para o caso do arquivo ter qualquer quantidade de espaços depois do `:`, e `[A-F]` para pegar as notas de "A" a "F" (foi só um exemplo, troque pelo intervalo que fizer mais sentido).

Mas como neste você só quer pegar explicitamente por "B", a primeira opção é mais simples. Eu usaria `[A-F]` se eu quisesse pegar a nota, independente do valor. Mas como só quero os que tem "B", não precisa disso.

---

E acho que neste caso, regex é uma complicação desnecessária. Se o formato é sempre esse ("nome: nota"), me parece mais simples usar [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
alunosComNotaB = []
with open('grades.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        nome, nota = linha.split(':')
        if nota.strip() == 'B':
            alunosComNotaB.append(nome)
```

Usei [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) para eliminar os espaços no início e fim (pois vi que algumas linhas têm espaço depois da nota).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação completa, consegui ter uma noção das melhores aproximações do problema.

abrç